# What is the difference between -DNDEBUG and -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS flags

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build-settings

I've tried `FauxPas` source code analyzer and it showed me that I am missing `-DNDEBUG` flag, with next description:

> This argument disables the C standard library assertion macro (as
>   defined in assert.h).

Though, when I check my build settings I found very similar by description flag `-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1`.

So I wonder now. Do I really need the flag that `FauxPas` suggests or I am fine with the one I have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NDEBUG` disables `assert()`, which is part of the C standard library. `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` disables `NSAssert()` which is part of Foundation. You generally will require both if you have both kinds of assertions in your code.

Comment: You wrote `NDEBUG`, but I asked about `DNDEBUG` is it the same?

Comment: The first -D is for "define".  -DNDEBUG means "define NDEBUG"

Comment: so how does "define" affects the DNDEBUG? its like saying define disable assert() ?

Comment: @gfdsal Correct. It creates a pre-processor macro `NDEBUG` with the value of 1.